# Can the word "luxury" be used as a concrete noun?

Tags: meaning, grammar, nouns, word-usage

I was wondering if we can use the word "luxury" to refer to a "luxurious item",

For example, are the sentences below considered grammatical? :

1. I have a luxury.
2. I have one luxury.
3. I have three luxuries.

Comment: No, you cannot. But, for example, you can say "I have two luxury Porshe" or "I love the luxury".

Comment: "[blah-blah] are no longer luxuries but necessities today".  "These are the couple of luxuries I allow myself once in a while".  So, you have the usage there, though *one luxury* or *two luxuries* on a standalone basis would sound clearly awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Luxury* is an [abstract object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_object), but it can be countable, and you can use it to refer to a certain luxurious item.  All the sentences you have in the question are grammatical. You can say "the divan is a luxury", or "I have the luxury of a Corvette" even "I have a luxury" (properly explained with context); but *luxury* by itself doesn't mean anything specifically physical.

Answer (score 3):

I must disagree with the comment implying *luxury* can't be used as in OP's three examples. [This NGram for *"one luxury is"*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one%20luxury%20is&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) returns nearly 3000 results, most of which treat a "luxury" as a countable noun.

I don't much like OP's first example, but we don't really have much context, and I certainly don't dispute it on grammatical grounds. The others seem unremarkable to me - [here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22had%20two%20luxuries%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are many written instances of *"had two luxuries"*, for example.

One luxury I allow myself on ELU is disputing unsubstantiable statements. Another is using words like *unsubstantiable* (incapable of being [substantiated](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=substantiate&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&psj=1&ei=8jpyT8GhK4Tf8QOJnJl1&ved=0CDIQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=f66d7c49905cd037&biw=1316&bih=902)), despite my browser spell-checker objecting!

Comment: +1. Desert Island Discs, anyone?

Comment: @Andrew Leach: Jinx! I actually Googled **"Desert Island Discs" luxury** when writing this, hoping presenters Roy Plomley, Michael Parkinson, Sue Lawley, or Kirsty Young might be in the habit of asking *"...and what luxury have you chosen?"*. It turns out they invariably say *"luxury **item**"*, but Google Books shows many of us are a bit "looser" in our phrasing.

Comment: Let's take an example: "His one luxury is tobacco".  That's not concrete.  Countable doesn't mean concrete.

Comment: @Daniel: By *concrete/countable*, I mean *concrete and/or countable* as distinguished from abstract and/or uncountable nouns which can't normally by preceded by an article (I almost hate to say it, but being slightly loose with syntax/terminology is another luxury I allow myself here on ELU sometimes! :)

Comment: Luxury is an abstract quality.  It may be misleading that it is countable, but the fact that there is such a thing as a single instance of luxury does not mean that *a luxury* denotes anything physical.  It is always used to *assign* a quality to a concrete object.  This can be accomplished in either noun or adjective form - *a luxurious car* or *the car is a luxury*.  To equate this issue to another example, consider the sentence *an injustice has been committed*.  *Injustice* is countable, but not concrete.

Comment: So am I using a different definition of *concrete* than you are?  I wonder which the OP meant? (-1 until you can show that *countable* = *concrete*, upon which I'll modify my perspective.  But so far you've only shown me that you have a different definition of *concrete*)

Comment: @Daniel: I think you're conflating syntactic and semantic categories there. If I were Dr Johnson, I would refute it *thus*, by snatching your cigar and grinding it under my heel (always assuming you were availing yourself of that luxury, while we were debating the issue! :). I just don't see a problem with ["had two luxuries"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22had+two+luxuries%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: ...my concern here is not to quibble over the precise usage of countable/concrete/etc. I'm simply disagreeing with the substance of your answer, which appears to say OP can't either use an article before, or count, *luxuries*.

Comment: No, I said it *is* countable.  I said it *isn't* concrete. Here's a quote: "You can use luxury as a countable noun, but it's still not concrete."  I also said his sentences are grammatical, all of which use *luxury* countably.

Comment: @Daniel: I'm lost. What exactly does the first word *No* in your answer mean? I don't much like his example (1), but (2) and (3) seem fine. The only other thing *No* could refere to is OP's *can [I] use the word "luxury" to refer to a "luxurious item"?* - to which my answer is **Yes**.

Comment: The title of the question is "Can the word “luxury” be used as a concrete noun?"  Maybe I shouldn't start out by answering the title... there, I edited.

Comment: @Daniel: Ooops. I confess I never even noticed that word in the title itself. We seem to be quibbling about nothing other than your exclusive focus on the title, and my total failure to look up above OP's question text. I will cancel my downvote against your answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid I'm not so sure about your answer, since it first "disagrees" with my answer, then establishes that *luxury* is countable (which I also said), then has a light blurb about disputing my "insubstantiable statement".

Comment: @Daniel: The system is getting irritated with this back-and-forth. I was primarily taking issue with the comment immediately under the question, which so far as I can see says OP's postulate is wrong. Your answer was somewhat "collateral damage", but if you want to defend it to the death, that's your choice. I'm not fighting any more.

Comment: Fair enough, let's call it quits.

Comment: I don't need money; family and friends are my two luxuries.